# Replace single quote with double quote in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have file that use JSON syntax but with single quote. I'm using QTextStream to load data from file to string. Then I use built-in replace function 
`QS_fileValue.replace(QString("\'"),QString("\""));`
but my string looks like `"{\"zmax\": 50,` and I have no idea how to remove this escape sequences. If I save it to file it looks fine, but if I load it from new file it still have escape sequences.

Comment: What do you mean by "string looks like"? Most debuggers will display the strings escaped; that doesn't mean there are escape characters in memory.

Comment: your question isn't very clear

Comment: @SebastianRedl I mean that `QJsonDocument::fromJson` is not able to read that string, but when I edit this file in notepad by find and replace it works and I'm able to get data from file.

Comment: @MaciejL what does `QJsonParseError::errorString()` say? And is your file utf-8 encoded?

Comment: @Nitro.de It is utf-8 file, `QJsonParseError::errorString()` return 7, so it turns out that i was looking in wrong place, thanks you, now it's work.

Comment: @MaciejL glad i could help. Please tell us what was wrong maybe as an answer to your own question and tell us what you did to notice your first guess was wrong

Comment: @Nitro.de JSON contained string `u'Fracturing'`. I've learned one important thing, never believe if someone say it is a file with proper syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the single quote or explicitly define everything as a QString.

Do this instead:

```
QS_fileValue.replace("'", "\"");
```

Alternatively you can replace by character code to test to see if this has the same effect:

```
QS_fileValue.replace(0x27,0x22)
```

However your suggestion also worked for me.

I'd say the debugger is simply displaying the " character escaped.

Comment: I've tried that way also and still have the same problem that `QJsonDocument::fromJson` is not able to read it.

Comment: See my updated suggestion. Also how are you saving the data to file? Can you post the code?

Comment: It work, turns out I was looking in wrong place. After replace ' with " one string was wrong, and I miss that.